# WP Query to custom post type or category

Tags: php, custom-post-type, wordpress

i've searching with no luck how to generate a custom wp_query that retrieve an specific category and post type = 'post' or just custom post type = 'bc'.

The idea is to "merge" in a page all posts with custom type 'bc' or category 'my-cat'.

I did a custom query without wp_query, just a custom made and ran it but seems to be very memory expensive and apparently is breaking my db, thats why i would like to try it as arguments of a new WP_Query().

Any idea please? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See this section in the wordpress codex.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'bc', // or 'post' if you don't want your custom post type
    'category_name' => 'my-cat'
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: But, wont that get me the post type bc AND category my-cat ? i need post_Ttype post and category mycat or post_type bc. So if i have a post in the category it will be returned and also the bc post type content.

Comment: This should give you what you are looking for, but why not try it and find out?

Comment: I did, that's why i'm asking, i dont know too much wordpress, but i got no results because i dont have any post_type = 'bc' with category_name = 'my-cat', thats why i want an "or" kind of operator :-\